# вычисление среднего числа

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Чисто математический вопрос, немного простой и туповатый. Идет процесс подсчитывания среднего числа при каждом определенном процессе. В 30 минут например их было 1,5к процессов. По результатам 30 мин я получаю свое средние например 12,93 и обнуляю данные и с новым процессом заново 30мин идет вычисление. В итоге у меня вторая 30минутка дала 15,30. Я беру и складываю (12,93+15,30)/2 и в итоге за 2 периода у меня среднее 14,115. А если я не буду фиксировать каждые 30 мин и посчитаю средние через час и в процессе данные были абсолютно те же, то ответ совпадет, будет ли снова 14,115?

Comment: нет. будут разные.

Comment: если точность не очень важна. то цифры примерно будут одинаковые при разбросе в 1500.

Comment: Равенство будет соблюдаться только если в течение обоих 30-минутных периодов количество замеров было строго одинаковым.

Comment: и нет ни каких простых фокусов как можно это го избежать? или слишком сложно?

Comment: Простой фокус - учитывать количество измерений на каждом интервале и считать по формуле среднего взвешенного: `M = (M1 * N1 + M2 * N2) / (N1 + N2)`. M1 и N1 - среднее и количество измерений на первом интервале.  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Среднее_арифметическое_взвешенное

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался работает. Тут можно даже упростить т.к. M1*N1 = сумме всех переменных и заведома известна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

числа будут разные. Лучше будет, если вы запомните оба показателя и подсчитаете в конце. 
Пусть в первые 30 минут у вас было N1(1.5к) процессов и сумма этих процессов равна S1.

вторые 30 минут было N2 процессов и сумма этих процессов равна S2.

Тогда общее среднее арифметическое будет `(S1+S2)/(N1+N2)` То есть сумма всех процессов разделить на количество всех процессов.

Предствьте так,  у вас есть множество {1,2,6} и {200,300,400,300}.
сред ариф. первого множества будет 3, а второго будет 300. (3+300)/2 = 151.5

а если считать сред. ариф всех чисел, то получится (1+2+6+200+300+400+300)/7=172.7...

Comment: Тогда почему с другими цифрами ответ одинаковый. {2,4,2,4} и  {2,3,5,14,}     (3 + 6) / 2 = 4,5  и  2+4+2+4+2+3+5+14 / 8 = 4,5

Comment: очень интересно и проблематично..а если добавить еще одно число к одному из множеств то тогда результаты не будут совпадать. {2,4,2,4,3} = 3. В первом и втором случаи у нас остается ответ 3, но когда мы будет считать большую средне то уже будем делить на больше числе и того (2+4+2+4+5+2+3+5+14) / 9 =  4,3.   Я так понимаю как не крути тут справедливая средняя только та что считается длинной формулой???разбиение на части уже искажает ответ?  Ведь разбиение на части я сделал лишь для удобства у себя в программе а выходит не тот результат

Comment: @FX_Sektor: Это зависит не от "цифр", а от их количества. Равенство будет соблюдаться только если в обоих наборах содержится одинаковое количество чисел.